# In which scripture does Lord Hanuman say that Advaita, Dvaita and Vishishtadvaita are all valid philosophies?

Tags: rama, hanuman, identification-request

I have found several [blogs](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/hanuman-perfect-proponent-of-advaita-vishishtadvaita-dvaita) where Lord Rama asks Lord Hanuman how He perceives Him. Lord Hanuman replies:

> देहबुद्ध्या तु दासोऽस्मि जीवबुद्ध्या त्वदंशकः।
>   आत्मबुद्ध्या त्वमेवाहमिति मे निश्चिता मतिः॥
>
> Deha-Buddhyaa Tu Daso.smi Jiva-Buddhyaa Tvad-Anshakah |
>   Aatma-Buddhyaa Tvam-Evaaham Iti Me Nishchita Matih ||
>
> **English Translation**: “O Lord, while I identify myself with my body, I am Thy servant (Dvaita). When I consider myself as Individual Soul, I am Thy part (Vishishtadvaita). But when I look upon myself as the Spirit (Atma), I am one with Thee Thyself (Advaita).”

The above verse seems to indirectly say that all the 3 Vedanta philosophies-
Advaita, Vishishtadvaita & Dvaita are all valid philosophies. Which scripture contains the above verse?

Thanks.

Jai Shri Rama! Jai Bajrangbali! Hare Krishna! Jai Sriman Narayana!

Comment: Identifying oneself with the body is not Dvaita. Rest implication is okay.

Comment: एषः श्लोकः महर्षि वाल्मीकि कृत रामायण अन्तर्गत अस्ति।

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Initially I guessed this should be from Muktika Upanishad or Adhyatma Ramayana texts like Rama Hridayam or Rama Gita but those parts don't contain this verse.

According to [this discussion on advaita-vedanta.org](http://lists.advaita-vedanta.org/archives/advaita-l/2014-February/036518.html),

> Thus, Shri.Lingamurthy Garu composed a magnus opus called **“sItArAmAnjanEya-samvAda”**. A beautiful work and gloss on “rAma-hridaya” which culminates in universal vision of advaita. This was said to be composed in 1760 AD. The following are the last verses. After imparting the Upanishad vidya to Shri Anjaneya, Lord ramachandra asks shri Anjaneya whether He had understood the teaching properly or not.

I searched for the work sItArAmAnjanEya-samvAda but it seems in Telugu language, so, I can't check it.

While searching on [Sanskrit Documents](http://sanskritdocuments.org), I found very similar verse contained in [Guha Gita](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/guhagiitaa.html?lang=sa):

> देहबुद्ध्या भवद्दासः जीवबुद्ध्या त्वदंशकः ।
>  आत्मबुद्ध्या त्वमेवाहं सद्गतोऽस्मिन् न संशयः ॥ ६.२॥

By seeing the nature of Guha Gita, it seems verses are mainly  taken from different scriptures. So, others sources are needs to be checked.

---

Some claims this seems from Adi Shankaracharya's Hanuman Pancharatna Stotram but I couldn't find in it except [this HanumanSukti](http://www.transliteral.org/pages/z80314051822/view). Hanumat Sukti is one portion of the book Sukti Sudhagar by Gitapress. You can view/get book from Internet Archive : [Hindi Book Sukti Sudhakar By Gita Press](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookSuktiSudhakarByGitaPress) .

Page no. 47 of [pdf](https://archive.org/download/HindiBookSuktiSudhakarByGitaPress/Hindi%20Book-Sukti-Sudhakar%20by%20Gita%20Press.pdf) / page no. 43 of book:

> [image]

However, let me clear that [Adi Shankaracharya's Hanumat Pancharatnam](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_hanumaana/hanumatpancha.html?lang=sa) doesn't contain it. This may be case or wrong/missing reference I think.